# ASP.NET validators and jquery

Tags: jquery, asp.net, validation

I have an **addressControl**, which contains several textboxes and RequiredFieldValidators.

A page contains 2 **addressControls** and checkbox. If the checkbox is checked, second **address control** (properly speaking - all textboxes inside **addressControl**) must be disabled without postback and vise versa.

I need to do it using jquery without postback. But I've encountered with some problems. One problem is RequiredFieldValidators on the second address control become visible even the checkbox is checked (and address control is disabled).

UPDAT2E:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en">
<head id="Head1"><title>

</title><link href="/Styles/Site.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" /><link href="/Styles/jqueryui.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <script   src="/Scripts/jquery/jquery-1.5.1.min.js" type="text/javascript" ></script>
    <script   src="/scripts/jquery/jquery-ui-1.8.6.custom.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script   src="/scripts/jquery/jquery.ui.datepicker-ru.js" type="text/javascript"></script>


<script type="text/javascript">

function Validator_Enable(e, v) {

    if (v == false) {
        e.isvalid = !v; //if disabling the validator then marked it as valid.
    }
    e.enabled = v;
    //ValidatorValidate(e); DON'T DO
    ValidatorUpdateIsValid();
}

    $(document).ready(function () {
        $('#MainContent_txtRegistrationDate').datepicker();
        checkboxHandlerObj.init();
    });

    var checkboxHandlerObj =
    {
        init: function () {
            $('#customerServices input:checkbox[class="parent"]').click(checkboxHandlerObj.parentClicked);
            $('#customerServices input:checkbox[class^="parent-"]').click(checkboxHandlerObj.childClicked);
            $('#MainContent_chkLegalAddress').click(checkboxHandlerObj.chkLegalAddressClick);
        },

        parentClicked: function () {
            if ($(this).attr('checked')) {
                $('#customerServices input:checkbox[class="parent-' + $(this).attr('id') + '"]').attr('checked', 'checked');
            }
            else {
                $('#customerServices input:checkbox[class="parent-' + $(this).attr('id') + '"]').removeAttr('checked');
            }
        },

        childClicked: function () {
            var temp = $(this).attr('class').split('-');
            var parentId = temp[1];

            if ($(this).attr('checked')) {
                $('#' + parentId).attr('checked', 'checked');
            }
            else {
                var atLeastOneEnabled = false;
                $('#customerServices input:checkbox[class="' + $(this).attr('class') + '"]').each(function () {
                    if ($(this).attr('checked')) {
                        atLeastOneEnabled = true;
                    }
                });
                if (!atLeastOneEnabled) {
                    $('#' + parentId).removeAttr('checked');
                }
            }
        },

        chkLegalAddressClick: function () {
            if ($(this).is(':checked')) {
                $('#legalAddress :input').attr('disabled', true);
                var a = $('#legalAddress').find('span').attr('id');

                if (a.indexOf('RequiredFieldValidator') != -1) {

                    $('#legalAddress').find('span').each(function () {
                        if ($(this).attr("controltovalidate").length > 0) {
                            Validator_Enable(this, false);
                        }

                    })

                }
                else {
                    $('#legalAddress :input').removeAttr('disabled');
                    //$('#legalAddress').find('span').attr('style', 'visibility:visible');
                }
            }

        }
    }



</script>


</head>
<body>
    <form method="post" action="CustomerRegistration.aspx" onsubmit="javascript:return WebForm_OnSubmit();" id="Form1">
<div class="aspNetHidden">
<input type="hidden" name="__EVENTTARGET" id="__EVENTTARGET" value="" />
<input type="hidden" name="__EVENTARGUMENT" id="__EVENTARGUMENT" value="" />
<input type="hidden" name="__VIEWSTATE" id="__VIEWSTATE" value="/wEPDwUKMTc4MDEyMTgyMGQYAwUeX19Db250cm9sc1JlcXVpcmVQb3N0QmFja0tleV9fFgMFKWN0bDAwJEhlYWRMb2dpblZpZXckSGVhZExvZ2luU3RhdHVzJGN0bDAxBSljdGwwMCRIZWFkTG9naW5WaWV3JEhlYWRMb2dpblN0YXR1cyRjdGwwMwUhY3RsMDAkTWFpbkNvbnRlbnQkY2hrTGVnYWxBZGRyZXNzBRpjdGwwMCRtbnVOYXZpZ2F0aW9uVG9wTWVudQ8PZAUtQ3VzdG9tZXIn0Ytc0KDQtdCz0LjRgdGC0YDQsNGG0LjRjyBjdXN0b21lcidhZAUTY3RsMDAkSGVhZExvZ2luVmlldw8PZAIBZJWMKDc9T2zXH3REtHMTFcrLZQYH+1pHSEh2hOfM6MRL" />
</div>

<script type="text/javascript">
//<![CDATA[
var theForm = document.forms['Form1'];
if (!theForm) {
    theForm = document.Form1;
}
function __doPostBack(eventTarget, eventArgument) {
    if (!theForm.onsubmit || (theForm.onsubmit() != false)) {
        theForm.__EVENTTARGET.value = eventTarget;
        theForm.__EVENTARGUMENT.value = eventArgument;
        theForm.submit();
    }
}
//]]>
</script>



<div>

<fieldset>
    <legend>Фактический адрес клиента</legend>
<div>
<div>Страна</div>
    <span id="MainContent_ucActualAddress_RequiredFieldValidator4" style="visibility:hidden;">
            <span class="error">Введите страну</span>
    </span>

    <div><input name="ctl00$MainContent$ucActualAddress$txtCountry" type="text" id="MainContent_ucActualAddress_txtCountry" /></div>
</div>


<div>
<div>Город</div>
    <span id="MainContent_ucActualAddress_RequiredFieldValidator1" style="visibility:hidden;">
            <span class="error">Введите город</span>
    </span>
    <div><input name="ctl00$MainContent$ucActualAddress$txtCity" type="text" id="MainContent_ucActualAddress_txtCity" /></div>

</div>


<div>
<div>Улица</div>
    <span id="MainContent_ucActualAddress_RequiredFieldValidator2" style="visibility:hidden;">
            <span class="error">Введите улицу</span>
    </span>
    <div><input name="ctl00$MainContent$ucActualAddress$txtStreet" type="text" id="MainContent_ucActualAddress_txtStreet" /></div>
</div>

<div>
<div>Дом</div>
    <span id="MainContent_ucActualAddress_RequiredFieldValidator3" style="visibility:hidden;">
            <span class="error">Введите корпус</span>
    </span>
    <div> <input name="ctl00$MainContent$ucActualAddress$txtBlock" type="text" id="MainContent_ucActualAddress_txtBlock" /></div>
</div>


<div>
<div>Строение</div>
    <span id="MainContent_ucActualAddress_RequiredFieldValidator5" style="visibility:hidden;">
            <span class="error">Введите юридический адрес</span>
    </span>
    <div><input name="ctl00$MainContent$ucActualAddress$txtBuilding" type="text" id="MainContent_ucActualAddress_txtBuilding" /></div>
</div>



</fieldset></div>

<input id="MainContent_chkLegalAddress" type="checkbox" name="ctl00$MainContent$chkLegalAddress" /><label for="MainContent_chkLegalAddress">Совпадает с фактическим адресом</label>
<div id="legalAddress">


<fieldset>
    <legend>Юридический адрес клиента</legend>
<div>
<div>Страна</div>
    <span id="MainContent_ucLegalAddress_RequiredFieldValidator4" style="visibility:hidden;">
            <span class="error">Введите страну</span>

    </span>
    <div><input name="ctl00$MainContent$ucLegalAddress$txtCountry" type="text" id="MainContent_ucLegalAddress_txtCountry" /></div>
</div>


<div>
<div>Город</div>
    <span id="MainContent_ucLegalAddress_RequiredFieldValidator1" style="visibility:hidden;">
            <span class="error">Введите город</span>
    </span>

    <div><input name="ctl00$MainContent$ucLegalAddress$txtCity" type="text" id="MainContent_ucLegalAddress_txtCity" /></div>
</div>


<div>
<div>Улица</div>
    <span id="MainContent_ucLegalAddress_RequiredFieldValidator2" style="visibility:hidden;">
            <span class="error">Введите улицу</span>
    </span>
    <div><input name="ctl00$MainContent$ucLegalAddress$txtStreet" type="text" id="MainContent_ucLegalAddress_txtStreet" /></div>

</div>


<div>
<div>Дом</div>
    <span id="MainContent_ucLegalAddress_RequiredFieldValidator3" style="visibility:hidden;">
            <span class="error">Введите корпус</span>
    </span>
    <div> <input name="ctl00$MainContent$ucLegalAddress$txtBlock" type="text" id="MainContent_ucLegalAddress_txtBlock" /></div>
</div>


<div>
<div>Строение</div>
    <span id="MainContent_ucLegalAddress_RequiredFieldValidator5" style="visibility:hidden;">
            <span class="error">Введите юридический адрес</span>
    </span>
    <div><input name="ctl00$MainContent$ucLegalAddress$txtBuilding" type="text" id="MainContent_ucLegalAddress_txtBuilding" /></div>
</div>


</fieldset>
</div>






    <div>
        <input type="submit" name="ctl00$MainContent$btnSubmit" value="Сохранить" onclick="javascript:WebForm_DoPostBackWithOptions(new WebForm_PostBackOptions(&quot;ctl00$MainContent$btnSubmit&quot;, &quot;&quot;, true, &quot;&quot;, &quot;&quot;, false, false))" id="MainContent_btnSubmit" /> 
        <input type="submit" name="ctl00$MainContent$btnCancel" value="Отменить" onclick="javascript:WebForm_DoPostBackWithOptions(new WebForm_PostBackOptions(&quot;ctl00$MainContent$btnCancel&quot;, &quot;&quot;, true, &quot;&quot;, &quot;&quot;, false, false))" id="MainContent_btnCancel" />
    </div>



        </div>
        <div class="clear">

        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="footer">
         <div align="right">
            версия: 1.0.0.24109
         </div>
    </div>





<script type="text/javascript">
//<![CDATA[
var Page_Validators =  new Array(document.getElementById("MainContent_RequiredFieldValidator1"), document.getElementById("MainContent_RequiredFieldValidator2"), document.getElementById("MainContent_RequiredFieldValidator3"), document.getElementById("MainContent_ucActualAddress_RequiredFieldValidator4"), document.getElementById("MainContent_ucActualAddress_RequiredFieldValidator1"), document.getElementById("MainContent_ucActualAddress_RequiredFieldValidator2"), document.getElementById("MainContent_ucActualAddress_RequiredFieldValidator3"), document.getElementById("MainContent_ucActualAddress_RequiredFieldValidator5"), document.getElementById("MainContent_ucLegalAddress_RequiredFieldValidator4"), document.getElementById("MainContent_ucLegalAddress_RequiredFieldValidator1"), document.getElementById("MainContent_ucLegalAddress_RequiredFieldValidator2"), document.getElementById("MainContent_ucLegalAddress_RequiredFieldValidator3"), document.getElementById("MainContent_ucLegalAddress_RequiredFieldValidator5"), document.getElementById("MainContent_RequiredFieldValidator6"), document.getElementById("MainContent_RequiredFieldValidator7"), document.getElementById("MainContent_RequiredFieldValidator8"), document.getElementById("MainContent_RequiredFieldValidator9"), document.getElementById("MainContent_RequiredFieldValidator10"), document.getElementById("MainContent_RequiredFieldValidator11"), document.getElementById("MainContent_RequiredFieldValidator12"), document.getElementById("MainContent_RequiredFieldValidator13"), document.getElementById("MainContent_RequiredFieldValidator14"), document.getElementById("MainContent_RequiredFieldValidator15"), document.getElementById("MainContent_RequiredFieldValidator16"));
//]]>
</script>

<script type="text/javascript">
//<![CDATA[
var MainContent_RequiredFieldValidator1 = document.all ? document.all["MainContent_RequiredFieldValidator1"] : document.getElementById("MainContent_RequiredFieldValidator1");
MainContent_RequiredFieldValidator1.controltovalidate = "MainContent_txtShortName";
MainContent_RequiredFieldValidator1.evaluationfunction = "RequiredFieldValidatorEvaluateIsValid";
MainContent_RequiredFieldValidator1.initialvalue = "";
var MainContent_RequiredFieldValidator2 = document.all ? document.all["MainContent_RequiredFieldValidator2"] : document.getElementById("MainContent_RequiredFieldValidator2");
MainContent_RequiredFieldValidator2.controltovalidate = "MainContent_txtPropertyForm";
MainContent_RequiredFieldValidator2.evaluationfunction = "RequiredFieldValidatorEvaluateIsValid";
MainContent_RequiredFieldValidator2.initialvalue = "";
var MainContent_RequiredFieldValidator3 = document.all ? document.all["MainContent_RequiredFieldValidator3"] : document.getElementById("MainContent_RequiredFieldValidator3");
MainContent_RequiredFieldValidator3.controltovalidate = "MainContent_txtFullName";
MainContent_RequiredFieldValidator3.evaluationfunction = "RequiredFieldValidatorEvaluateIsValid";
MainContent_RequiredFieldValidator3.initialvalue = "";
var MainContent_ucActualAddress_RequiredFieldValidator4 = document.all ? document.all["MainContent_ucActualAddress_RequiredFieldValidator4"] : document.getElementById("MainContent_ucActualAddress_RequiredFieldValidator4");
MainContent_ucActualAddress_RequiredFieldValidator4.controltovalidate = "MainContent_ucActualAddress_txtCountry";
MainContent_ucActualAddress_RequiredFieldValidator4.evaluationfunction = "RequiredFieldValidatorEvaluateIsValid";
MainContent_ucActualAddress_RequiredFieldValidator4.initialvalue = "";
var MainContent_ucActualAddress_RequiredFieldValidator1 = document.all ? document.all["MainContent_ucActualAddress_RequiredFieldValidator1"] : document.getElementById("MainContent_ucActualAddress_RequiredFieldValidator1");
MainContent_ucActualAddress_RequiredFieldValidator1.controltovalidate = "MainContent_ucActualAddress_txtCity";
MainContent_ucActualAddress_RequiredFieldValidator1.evaluationfunction = "RequiredFieldValidatorEvaluateIsValid";
MainContent_ucActualAddress_RequiredFieldValidator1.initialvalue = "";
var MainContent_ucActualAddress_RequiredFieldValidator2 = document.all ? document.all["MainContent_ucActualAddress_RequiredFieldValidator2"] : document.getElementById("MainContent_ucActualAddress_RequiredFieldValidator2");
MainContent_ucActualAddress_RequiredFieldValidator2.controltovalidate = "MainContent_ucActualAddress_txtStreet";
MainContent_ucActualAddress_RequiredFieldValidator2.evaluationfunction = "RequiredFieldValidatorEvaluateIsValid";
MainContent_ucActualAddress_RequiredFieldValidator2.initialvalue = "";
var MainContent_ucActualAddress_RequiredFieldValidator3 = document.all ? document.all["MainContent_ucActualAddress_RequiredFieldValidator3"] : document.getElementById("MainContent_ucActualAddress_RequiredFieldValidator3");
MainContent_ucActualAddress_RequiredFieldValidator3.controltovalidate = "MainContent_ucActualAddress_txtBlock";
MainContent_ucActualAddress_RequiredFieldValidator3.evaluationfunction = "RequiredFieldValidatorEvaluateIsValid";
MainContent_ucActualAddress_RequiredFieldValidator3.initialvalue = "";
var MainContent_ucActualAddress_RequiredFieldValidator5 = document.all ? document.all["MainContent_ucActualAddress_RequiredFieldValidator5"] : document.getElementById("MainContent_ucActualAddress_RequiredFieldValidator5");
MainContent_ucActualAddress_RequiredFieldValidator5.controltovalidate = "MainContent_ucActualAddress_txtBuilding";
MainContent_ucActualAddress_RequiredFieldValidator5.evaluationfunction = "RequiredFieldValidatorEvaluateIsValid";
MainContent_ucActualAddress_RequiredFieldValidator5.initialvalue = "";
var MainContent_ucLegalAddress_RequiredFieldValidator4 = document.all ? document.all["MainContent_ucLegalAddress_RequiredFieldValidator4"] : document.getElementById("MainContent_ucLegalAddress_RequiredFieldValidator4");
MainContent_ucLegalAddress_RequiredFieldValidator4.controltovalidate = "MainContent_ucLegalAddress_txtCountry";
MainContent_ucLegalAddress_RequiredFieldValidator4.evaluationfunction = "RequiredFieldValidatorEvaluateIsValid";
MainContent_ucLegalAddress_RequiredFieldValidator4.initialvalue = "";
var MainContent_ucLegalAddress_RequiredFieldValidator1 = document.all ? document.all["MainContent_ucLegalAddress_RequiredFieldValidator1"] : document.getElementById("MainContent_ucLegalAddress_RequiredFieldValidator1");
MainContent_ucLegalAddress_RequiredFieldValidator1.controltovalidate = "MainContent_ucLegalAddress_txtCity";
MainContent_ucLegalAddress_RequiredFieldValidator1.evaluationfunction = "RequiredFieldValidatorEvaluateIsValid";
MainContent_ucLegalAddress_RequiredFieldValidator1.initialvalue = "";
var MainContent_ucLegalAddress_RequiredFieldValidator2 = document.all ? document.all["MainContent_ucLegalAddress_RequiredFieldValidator2"] : document.getElementById("MainContent_ucLegalAddress_RequiredFieldValidator2");
MainContent_ucLegalAddress_RequiredFieldValidator2.controltovalidate = "MainContent_ucLegalAddress_txtStreet";
MainContent_ucLegalAddress_RequiredFieldValidator2.evaluationfunction = "RequiredFieldValidatorEvaluateIsValid";
MainContent_ucLegalAddress_RequiredFieldValidator2.initialvalue = "";
var MainContent_ucLegalAddress_RequiredFieldValidator3 = document.all ? document.all["MainContent_ucLegalAddress_RequiredFieldValidator3"] : document.getElementById("MainContent_ucLegalAddress_RequiredFieldValidator3");
MainContent_ucLegalAddress_RequiredFieldValidator3.controltovalidate = "MainContent_ucLegalAddress_txtBlock";
MainContent_ucLegalAddress_RequiredFieldValidator3.evaluationfunction = "RequiredFieldValidatorEvaluateIsValid";
MainContent_ucLegalAddress_RequiredFieldValidator3.initialvalue = "";
var MainContent_ucLegalAddress_RequiredFieldValidator5 = document.all ? document.all["MainContent_ucLegalAddress_RequiredFieldValidator5"] : document.getElementById("MainContent_ucLegalAddress_RequiredFieldValidator5");
MainContent_ucLegalAddress_RequiredFieldValidator5.controltovalidate = "MainContent_ucLegalAddress_txtBuilding";
MainContent_ucLegalAddress_RequiredFieldValidator5.evaluationfunction = "RequiredFieldValidatorEvaluateIsValid";
MainContent_ucLegalAddress_RequiredFieldValidator5.initialvalue = "";
var MainContent_RequiredFieldValidator6 = document.all ? document.all["MainContent_RequiredFieldValidator6"] : document.getElementById("MainContent_RequiredFieldValidator6");
MainContent_RequiredFieldValidator6.controltovalidate = "MainContent_txtActivityScope";
MainContent_RequiredFieldValidator6.evaluationfunction = "RequiredFieldValidatorEvaluateIsValid";
MainContent_RequiredFieldValidator6.initialvalue = "";
var MainContent_RequiredFieldValidator7 = document.all ? document.all["MainContent_RequiredFieldValidator7"] : document.getElementById("MainContent_RequiredFieldValidator7");
MainContent_RequiredFieldValidator7.controltovalidate = "MainContent_txtPhone";
MainContent_RequiredFieldValidator7.evaluationfunction = "RequiredFieldValidatorEvaluateIsValid";
MainContent_RequiredFieldValidator7.initialvalue = "";
var MainContent_RequiredFieldValidator8 = document.all ? document.all["MainContent_RequiredFieldValidator8"] : document.getElementById("MainContent_RequiredFieldValidator8");
MainContent_RequiredFieldValidator8.controltovalidate = "MainContent_txtFax";
MainContent_RequiredFieldValidator8.evaluationfunction = "RequiredFieldValidatorEvaluateIsValid";
MainContent_RequiredFieldValidator8.initialvalue = "";
var MainContent_RequiredFieldValidator9 = document.all ? document.all["MainContent_RequiredFieldValidator9"] : document.getElementById("MainContent_RequiredFieldValidator9");
MainContent_RequiredFieldValidator9.controltovalidate = "MainContent_txtINN";
MainContent_RequiredFieldValidator9.evaluationfunction = "RequiredFieldValidatorEvaluateIsValid";
MainContent_RequiredFieldValidator9.initialvalue = "";
var MainContent_RequiredFieldValidator10 = document.all ? document.all["MainContent_RequiredFieldValidator10"] : document.getElementById("MainContent_RequiredFieldValidator10");
MainContent_RequiredFieldValidator10.controltovalidate = "MainContent_txtKPP";
MainContent_RequiredFieldValidator10.evaluationfunction = "RequiredFieldValidatorEvaluateIsValid";
MainContent_RequiredFieldValidator10.initialvalue = "";
var MainContent_RequiredFieldValidator11 = document.all ? document.all["MainContent_RequiredFieldValidator11"] : document.getElementById("MainContent_RequiredFieldValidator11");
MainContent_RequiredFieldValidator11.controltovalidate = "MainContent_txtSettlementAccount";
MainContent_RequiredFieldValidator11.evaluationfunction = "RequiredFieldValidatorEvaluateIsValid";
MainContent_RequiredFieldValidator11.initialvalue = "";
var MainContent_RequiredFieldValidator12 = document.all ? document.all["MainContent_RequiredFieldValidator12"] : document.getElementById("MainContent_RequiredFieldValidator12");
MainContent_RequiredFieldValidator12.controltovalidate = "MainContent_txtCorrespondentAccount";
MainContent_RequiredFieldValidator12.evaluationfunction = "RequiredFieldValidatorEvaluateIsValid";
MainContent_RequiredFieldValidator12.initialvalue = "";
var MainContent_RequiredFieldValidator13 = document.all ? document.all["MainContent_RequiredFieldValidator13"] : document.getElementById("MainContent_RequiredFieldValidator13");
MainContent_RequiredFieldValidator13.controltovalidate = "MainContent_txtBankName";
MainContent_RequiredFieldValidator13.evaluationfunction = "RequiredFieldValidatorEvaluateIsValid";
MainContent_RequiredFieldValidator13.initialvalue = "";
var MainContent_RequiredFieldValidator14 = document.all ? document.all["MainContent_RequiredFieldValidator14"] : document.getElementById("MainContent_RequiredFieldValidator14");
MainContent_RequiredFieldValidator14.controltovalidate = "MainContent_txtBIK";
MainContent_RequiredFieldValidator14.evaluationfunction = "RequiredFieldValidatorEvaluateIsValid";
MainContent_RequiredFieldValidator14.initialvalue = "";
var MainContent_RequiredFieldValidator15 = document.all ? document.all["MainContent_RequiredFieldValidator15"] : document.getElementById("MainContent_RequiredFieldValidator15");
MainContent_RequiredFieldValidator15.controltovalidate = "MainContent_txtBOSSName";
MainContent_RequiredFieldValidator15.evaluationfunction = "RequiredFieldValidatorEvaluateIsValid";
MainContent_RequiredFieldValidator15.initialvalue = "";
var MainContent_RequiredFieldValidator16 = document.all ? document.all["MainContent_RequiredFieldValidator16"] : document.getElementById("MainContent_RequiredFieldValidator16");
MainContent_RequiredFieldValidator16.controltovalidate = "MainContent_txtRegistrationDate";
MainContent_RequiredFieldValidator16.evaluationfunction = "RequiredFieldValidatorEvaluateIsValid";
MainContent_RequiredFieldValidator16.initialvalue = "";
//]]>
</script>

<script type='text/javascript'>new Sys.WebForms.Menu({ element: 'mnuNavigationTopMenu', disappearAfter: 500, orientation: 'horizontal', tabIndex: 0, disabled: false });</script>
<script type="text/javascript">
//<![CDATA[

var Page_ValidationActive = false;
if (typeof(ValidatorOnLoad) == "function") {
    ValidatorOnLoad();
}

function ValidatorOnSubmit() {
    if (Page_ValidationActive) {
        return ValidatorCommonOnSubmit();
    }
    else {
        return true;
    }
}
        //]]>
</script>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

client side disabling of validators in your case can be tricky. Do it as following

```
//e is the validator and v is true or false
function Validator_Enable(e, v) {

    if (v == false) {
        e.isvalid = !v; //if disabling the validator then marked it as valid.
    }
    e.enabled = v;
    //ValidatorValidate(e); DON'T DO
    ValidatorUpdateIsValid();
}


chkLegalAddressClick: function () {
            if ($(this).attr("checked")) {
                $('#legalAddress :input').attr('disabled', true);
                var a = $('#legalAddress').find('span').attr('id');
                if (a.indexOf('RequiredFieldValidator') != -1){
                    //a.attr('style', 'visibility:hidden');
                }
                $(Page_Validators).each(function(){
                      if ($(this).attr("id").indexOf("ucLegalAddress_RequiredFieldValidator")>-1)
                               Validator_Enable(this,false);
                });
            }
            else {
                $('#legalAddress :input').removeAttr('disabled');
                //$('#legalAddress').find('span').attr('style', 'visibility:visible');
            }
```

The trick in my code is the Validator_Enable function. You can also loop through the Page_Validators array on the client side with a for loop, look at the "controltovalidate" property of each validator to see if it is a validator you want to disable and pass it to Validator_Enable function.

If my answer has helped you please check the checkbox next to it to accept it and vote it up!

Comment: All addressControl's validators are inaccessible!

Comment: What do you mean inaccssible? If you open up your page in Firefox with Firebug installed and in Firebug's console simply type Page_Validators, click Run, can you see them in the returned list?

Comment: Also check the rendered HTML of the page, are the validators being rendered outside your legalAddress div? If they are then you will have to iterate over Page_Validators array and look at each validator from there, look at its controltovalidate property and try to find out if the this controltovalidate lives under legalAddress div

Comment: Yes in your case it won't work because your selector is wrong and subsequently your code in the if condition where you are doing this.isvalid is also wrong. I think you are missing on the concept here unfortunately. Can you paste the rendered HTML here so I can give you the exact code.

Comment: I have slightly modified my code to make it more generic. Try that first. If that doesn't work then copy paste your rendered HTML so I can see how your validators eventually get rendered.

Comment: $(this).attr("controltovalidate") is undefined

Answer (score 1):

What if you repeat your jquery code into this function?

```
 var prm = Sys.WebForms.PageRequestManager.getInstance();
    prm.add_endRequest(function () {
```

so:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

$(document).ready(function () {
    checkboxHandlerObj.init();
});

var prm = Sys.WebForms.PageRequestManager.getInstance();
        prm.add_endRequest(function () {
checkboxHandlerObj.init();
});

var checkboxHandlerObj =
{
    init: function () {
       $('#legalAddress  input:checkbox').click(checkboxHandlerObj.chkLegalAddressClick);
    },


    chkLegalAddressClick: function () {
        if ($(this).is(':checked')) {
            $('#legalAddress :input').attr('disabled', true);
            var a = $('#legalAddress').find('span').attr('id');
            if (a.indexOf('RequiredFieldValidator') != -1) {

                this.isvalid = true; //if disabling the validator then marked it as valid.
                this.enabled = false; 
                ValidatorUpdateIsValid();

            }
        }
        else {
            $('#legalAddress :input').removeAttr('disabled');

        }
    }

}
```

I'm not sure it will work but you can try it!

Comment: 1. checkboxHandlerObj is undefined 2.Sys is not defined

Answer (score 0):

You may find a Validator that I wrote useful. It allows you to specify a control (usually a checkbox) as a condition to determine whether a TextBox is required. You are free to modify the code, it is all available on my page [here](http://www.nathansokalski.com/code/ConditionalValidatorCtrl.aspx).